# Why contextmenu of chrome extension is not getting updated on right click?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

**Requirement:** To create context menu upon removal of already existing menus.

Preq: Connection between content.js to background.js is working fine.

**Sample code as below in background.js:**

```
if(some condition){

    chrome.contextMenus.removeAll(function() {                  
        chrome.contextMenus.create({
             "title": "title1",
             "id": "id1",
             "contexts": ['all']
        });
        
        chrome.contextMenus.create({
            title: "menu1",
            parentId: "id1",
            id: "menuid1",
            contexts:["all"]
        });
    })
    console.log('test remove and update') //this message getting printed directly after removeAll called as checked in debugger.
}
else{
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
          "title": "title1",
          "id": "id1",
          "contexts": ['all']
    });
    
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        title: "menu1",
        parentId: "id1",
        id: "menuid1",
        contexts:["all"]
    });

}
```

**Actual Result:** After `chrome.contextMenus.removeAll` called, `chrome.contextMenus.create` action is not happening as per debugger. I see console.log message getting prinited.

**Expected Result:** After `chrome.contextMenus.removeAll` called, `chrome.contextMenus.create` should be called.

Note: I can't use onInstalled event, I have to use `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener` only.